# Rails, transactional email and sender validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendinblue

I would like to use `Sendinblue` to send transactional email from my Rails web application. 
To configure my application to use Sendinblue I edited `config/environments/production.rb` as follows (NOTE: `fireworks.com` is just an example):

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'fireworks.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp-relay.sendinblue.com',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDINBLUE_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDINBLUE_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'fireworks.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  ...
end
```

Do I need any gem, like `sib-api-v3-sdk`? 
I suppose this gem is useful only for sending email using the Sendinblue API.

At Sendinblue I authenticated my domain 'fireworks.com' and created a sender, `noreply@fireworks.com`, which I would use for account activation.

```
app/mailers/application_mailer.rb

class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@fireworks.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

In order for me to use this sender, Sendinblue wants me to verify (or validate) it. 
Now the point is that `noreply@fireworks.com` does not exist. Michael Hartl in his tutorial uses `noreply@example.com`, I would use `noreply@fireworks.com` because I own the `fireworks.com` domain. 
Since I would not be able to validate the sender, I thought that the only solution would be creating in my server the `noreply` user account, configuring Postfix to receive email from Internet and adding an MX record to my DNS zone. 
I would maintain this configuration until I receive the validation email. 
Is this solution necessary? Do I have any other choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the point is that noreply@fireworks.com does not exist.

Before continuing, I want to point out that this is ultimately not a good practice. You'll want some address to receive and recognize bounces.

Having said that, I just checked their documentation and it says [here](https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000185270-What-is-a-verified-domain-on-SendinBlue-) that instead of validating individual email addresses, you can just validate the whole domain via DNS entry, file upload or by sending them an email.